# Get children for any level in tree structure but without theirs children using Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tree, spring-data-jpa, recursive-query

I have a `Folder` entity in Hibernate, like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "folders")
public class Folder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "folder_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Column(name = "sub_folders")
    private Set<Folder> childFolders = new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent", referencedColumnName = "folder_id", nullable = true)
    private Folder parent;

    public Folder() {
    }

}
```

I'm trying to write a finder method or custom query which will do what I wrote in the subject.

So if I send a request going like `folders/{parent_folder_id}`, let's say value being `1`, I should get objects `4` and `5`, but without their children, so not including `6,7,8 and 9`.

Ideally, hibernate query would be preferred. If not, any sql language is also fine. I'll try to tumble it up to hibernate.

This is what I got, I still get children...

```
@Query(value = "Select * from folders f where f.parent = ?1 ", nativeQuery = true)
Set<Folder> getFolders(int folder_id);
```

[image]

Comment: Use Lazy fetching for children

Comment: Does configuring the relationship as lazy and then use an explicit join fetch for the first level of children in the query work?

Comment: @JensSchauder I tried some others queries with lazy fetch type, but that didn't work. I'm Hibernate/Spring newbie. This is closes I got, I'm not even sure about the correct syntax on hibernate..

Comment: @MiljanPuletic For response which class your using. Can you share your full code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

1. make the default fetchtype lazy:

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
   @Column(name = "sub_folders")
   private Set<Folder> childFolders = new HashSet<>();
   ```
2. Use a `JOIN FETCH` in order to eagerly fetch the relationships you want.

   ```
   SELECT f FROM folders f JOIN FETCH f.childFolders
   ```

You probably can achieve something similar with entity graphs but I'm not sure about their interaction with queries.

Comment: Danke Jens, I'll try it later and see what and if I can pull something off.

Comment: I've tried with lazy fetch and tried with your query, no luck. Getting error that query is not formatted well.

Comment: There was an extra space in the query. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I need with following query:

```
 @Query(value = "Select folder_id, name, parent From folders f Where f.parent = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

This will give me just name of the folder and its Id.